# Jetpack Compose Exception: Snapshot is not open

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Snapshot is not open

androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.validateOpen(Snapshot.kt:1465)
androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.access$validateOpen(Snapshot.kt:1)
androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.MutableSnapshot.apply(Snapshot.kt:584)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.applyAndCheck(Recomposer.kt:822)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1092)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:105)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:456)
androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:425)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5647)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

The exception occurred on the MuMu emulator, Android version 6.0.1：

I use `minifyEnabled false` can solve this problem,
but use `-keep public class androidx.compose.*.**{*; }` can not be solved, if I use `minifyEnabled true`, is there any way to fix this exception？